# How to redirect to "Pay with a credit card" in Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have seen this question asked in numerous places, but I have to found a clear answer.
I am using a simple Paypal Buy now button, which simply points to a url like this:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&paymentaction=authorization&business=xxx&amount=1&currency_code=EUR&lc=US
```

Now, where this actually redirect depends on cookies, sometimes it redirects the user to login to Paypal with a button for credit card form, sometimes it redirects directly to the "Pay with a credit card" form where he enters credit card information without having to login to Paypal.

I want the second option by default. Is there a querystring parameter to achieve that?
Thanks
Themos

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to force the  "Don't have a PayPal Account" option to be expanded by tweaking your item button code.  Note, this is an undocumented tip and there's no guarantees as PayPal does change things behind the scenes but, still worth a try.   If you manually code your item button (meaning you did not use the online button creator) you can insert the following line in the HTML Form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">
```

Comment: You are f****ng genius! :)

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not.
It will open the credit card panel if it doesn't detect any previous *.paypal.com login cookies.
If it does, it'll open the login panel.